# Why does box-2 come to the right instead of at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand how CSS layouts work. I have some HTML and CSS as shown in the link below. The only difference between top half and bottom half of the picture is that in div with id navigation-side has role="navigation" in bottom half.

Question: In bottom half, Why is the box to the right and not below div with id navigation-side? What line(s) in CSS are affecting this box's placement? Is it following lines?

```
[role=navigation] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
}
[role=navigation] {                                                                                                                                                
    *zoom: 1;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative
}
```

If yes, how exactly does it work?

https://jsfiddle.net/mor5r1hu/

[image: Two boxes CSS layout]

Comment: Reduced Demo please...there is ***waaaay*** to much extraneous code in there. Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D, I understand the importance of reducing the code. But sometimes, it destroys what I am trying to understand.  Unfortunately, I tried a lot of ways and could only reduce html part (to 89 lines). The CSS part is actually simple but when I reduce it, the layout I posted is not longer showing up. First few lines of  css in jsfiddle is bootstrap (v2.2.2) From line 13, its custom CSS. I am pretty sure the answer is in CSS lines which have [role=navigation] (as shown in original question). Please see if you can answer it.